buton does not stay red after touching
I am trying to change the colour of the button to red after clicking on it but it does not stay red. Also get an error that the label for the button when printing is nil.
local widget = require("widget")
local seats = {}

local function createSeat(index)
    local angle = math.rad((index - 1) * 40)
    local radius = 150
    local x = display.contentCenterX + math.cos(angle) * radius+20
    local y = display.contentCenterY + math.sin(angle) * radius
     if x>display.contentCenterX+100 then x=x-50 end
    
    local seat = widget.newButton({
        label = "Seat " .. index,
        labelColor = { default={1,1,1}, over={0.5,0.5,0.5} },
        fontSize = 20,
        shape = "roundedRect",
        width = 80,
        height = 40,
        cornerRadius = 5,
        fillColor = { default={0,0,1,1}, over={0,0,0.8,1} }
    })
    seat.x = x
    seat.y = y
    table.insert(seats, seat)
end

for i = 1, 9 do
    createSeat(i)
end
------------FUnctions--------------------------------------
------buttons pressed
local function buttonPressed(event)
    local button = event.target
    if event.phase == "ended" then
        button:setFillColor(1, 0, 0) -- Change to red when pressed
        print("Button " .. button.label.text .. " pressed") -- Debug message
        return true
    end
end

for i = 1, #seats do
    seats[i]:addEventListener("touch", buttonPressed)
end


--------


A nitpick: it's an envent of touching, not clicking

no worries, fixing the title
